# Find docker file path according to container id

Tags: docker

I want to download Docker container logs to my local. I know my container's container id.

Now, I use `df -h` to find the docker file path. Like this `/data/docker/overlay2/ea3e1ad0ccdee0e41d83722dfc6bf913250abd57918fecabd1067736b3e44305/merged`. But I have multiple containers, it is difficult to know my container's file path.

How can I know `ea3e1ad0ccdee0e41d83722dfc6bf913250abd57918fecabd1067736b3e44305` according to my container id.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

List the containers

```
 docker ps
```

Navigate inside your container where the log is present.

```
 docker exec -it ContainerId bash
```

Locate your log within the container

```
bash-4.2$ cd yourapplication/path/log/
```

Exit Container

```
  bash-4.2$ exit
```

Copy to your Local location

```
 docker cp edd5064178db:yourapplication/path/log/request.log /your/local/location
```

Comment: This is a very correct answer. I use  `docker cp edd5064178db:yourapplication/path/log/request.log /your/local/location` to copy files .

Answer (score 13):

You can find the image layers associated with the containers using `docker inspect`.

There might be a cleaner solution, but I was able to find the container id with some help from `xargs` and `jq`.

```
docker ps -a -q | xargs docker inspect | jq '.[] | select(.GraphDriver.Data.LowerDir | contains("ea3e1ad0ccdee0e41d83722dfc6bf913250abd57918fecabd1067736b3e44305")) | .Id'
```

- `docker ps -a -q` to grab a list of all the container Ids.
- `xargs docker inspect` to get the details of each container.
- `jq` to search the list and return the `Id` of any containers referencing the image layer in the `GraphDriver` object.

Comment: How can this be done without `jq`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`docker ps`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#options) command with `--no-trunc` option like the following:

```
docker ps -a --no-trunc
```

You only see the first twelve digits of the container ID because the output is truncated by default.

Comment: Sorry, use this command, I only could find `/data/docker/containers` not `/data/docker/overlay2`, in fact, my logs store in `/data/docker/overlay2/~`

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the exact mergeddir (which is different from container id) like this:

```
$ docker inspect --format='{{json .GraphDriver.Data.MergedDir}}' container-id
"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/the-string-you-are-searching-for/merged"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `docker logs` command will copy the container process's stdout and stderr to its own stdout and stderr, and you can save them from there.  You can also configure `docker run` to send the logs to another service like your local syslog or a logstash installation somewhere (but this makes `docker logs` not work any more).

```
docker logs $CONTAINER_ID >$CONTAINER_ID.log 2>&1
```

If it's logging to a file, you can `docker cp` it out

```
docker cp $CONTAINER_ID/usr/local/apache2/logs/access.log $CONTAINER_ID.access.log
```

But it's better still to just start the container with a host directory bind-mounted on to your logs directory, so this isn't a problem

```
docker stop $CONTAINER_ID
docker rm $CONTAINER_ID
docker run -v $PWD/logs:/usr/local/apache2/logs ...
```

Directly accessing things in `/var/lib/docker` usually isn't considered a good idea.  The `overlay2` directories have *parts* of the per-image and per-container filesystems, *if* your system is using the "overlay2" storage driver (aufs and devicemapper used to both be fairly common and would keep things in different subdirectories).

Answer (score 0):

With below command

`docker inspect --format {{.Id}} "ContainerName"`

you will see the container mount id.

Answer (score 0):

if you have multiple container /images running use the below command .

```
 for  i in $(docker images -q );do docker inspect  $i |grep <the-string-you-are-searching-for>  ;echo $i ;done
```

or

```
for  i in $(docker ps -aq );do docker inspect  $i |grep <the-string-you-are-searching-for>  ;echo $i ;done
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are not routing your log to any cloud & being stored in local then run below command to get the file location where docker stores logs for containers -

If you know container ID then use following command to get the file name with location & then you can download or whatever you want to do with the same -

```
docker inspect --format={{.LogPath}} <ContainerID>
```

This command will give you location like /var/lib/docker/containers//